# JQuery Mobile Control in partialview does not have the right style

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In the regular view, `<a href="#" data-role="button">Button</a>` will give you a nice looking button. But if the above code is in a partial view, it only renders as a regular html link...

any way to make the controls in partial view work like the regular jquery controls?

Answer (score 2):

If you render it dynamically in your partial view, aften the "page loads" then the style would not be applied. what you would need to do then is to call "pagecreate" on the page.

```
$('#page').trigger('pagecreate');
```

if your link is in a listview, then youd also need to "refresh" your list like so:

```
$("#List").listview('refresh');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC 4 then all you have to do is add a reference to your Layout in your Partial View.

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

In my case I have separate Mobile views which were partial so I just added this to the .Mobile.cshtml files and it will infer the use of _Layout.Mobile.cshtml.